# vue created doesn't update after changing route params

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to make a search bar in my index component that is loading other components to show the results of the search and it is working for the first time when the route in any other url except the /search route which is the results page but when I am trying to do other search `created()` doesn't work / not called again with the new parameter's value .

`index.vue`

```js
methods: {
  search() {
    this.$router.push({ name: "search", params:{id:this.words}})
  }
}
```

**component search.vue**

```js
data() {
  return {
    videos: null
  }
},
created() {
  axios.get('/api/search/'+this.$route.params.id)
    .then(response=>(this.videos = response.data.data))
    .then(document.title='search - '+this.$route.params.id)
}
```

Comment: have you tried ``php artisan optimize:clear``

Comment: `created()` hook will run only once, it will not call your `/api` endpoint again. Consider calling a method doing the axios call or even a `watch`.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it
it is should be

```
window.location.replace("/search/"+this.words);
```

instead of

```
 this.$router.push({ name: "search", params:{id:this.words}})
```

Comment: No, this is not the way to go. You're nuking your whole Vue instance with that one. I recommend following Vue's API if you don't want to have crappy performance and persisting your state every 5 seconds.

Comment: I can't understand the harm in that, can you explain more?

Comment: And SPA works but creating quite a lot of things on client side, by using `window.location`, it's basically like doing a server-side navigation (like a wordpress website). Hence, you will download, parse and execute Vue, then you will go to another page by destroying the whole thing, then creating it from scratch again etc etc... It's **quite** non-efficient, will come with a LOT of drawbacks in terms of state persistency and overall not how modern JS frameworks work nowadays. Keep working with Vue to understand it's internals a bit better.